VSCode selecting text within " "
I just noticed this and it's kind of annoying. If I autocomplete className="" by pressing tab, the content is being highlighted and I feel like that messes up the Tailwind CSS IntelliSense extension because it doesn't detect it when I'm using "m-10" for example, it just shows m-0 in the autocomplete.
It is hard to explain so I made this GIF
https://imgur.com/910acgL
I checked the settings for some "highlighting options" in VSCode and for any extensions but I couldn't find anything.

Is the setting Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions disabled?

In your workspace, or global user configuration, add these lines:
{
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "strings": true
    }
}

This will give you back TailwindCSS autocompletion

I thought I already answered, this but apparently I didn't. I can use TailwindCSS autocompletion. It just doesn't show the right property of m-10 for example, as shown in the GIF. I feel like it has to do with the className being highlighted, which I don't know how to turn off.
